# pass Value From html Webpage to Nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I need your help I'am following this tutorial : https://github.com/codeadamca/arduino-from-nodejs and I upgrade the dependencies to "socket.io": "^4.6.1" and my Goal is to pass Data from my html page to my nodejs server using socketio but I keep getting error: `GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OVI3WYK 404 (Not Found)`
below is my code

my server:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync( 'index.html');

const { SerialPort } = require('serialport')
const { ReadlineParser } = require('@serialport/parser-readline')

const parser = new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r\n' });

var port = new SerialPort(
    { path: 'COM3', baudRate: 9600 , dataBits: 8, parity: 'none', stopBits: 1, flowControl: false}
    );

port.pipe(parser);
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(index);
});
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    
    socket.on('lights',function(data){
        
        console.log( data );
        
        port.write( data.status );
    
    });
    
});

app.listen(5500);
```

my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Communicating from Node.js to an Arduino</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Communicating from Node.js to an Arduino</h1>

        <button id="lightOn">Turn Light On</button>
        <button id="lightOff">Turn Light Off</button>

        <script>
            
        var socket = io();

        document.getElementById('lightOn').onclick = function() {
            
            socket.emit('lights', { "status":"1" });
                
        };
            
        document.getElementById('lightOff').onclick = function(){
               
            socket.emit('lights', { "status":"0" });
            
        };
        
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your server api? you have to put it in `io('serverAPI')`